# Class out of class variable in Python

Tags: python, class

is there a way how I can get class out of class variable?

```
class T():
    x = 5
    y = 6
```

My function accepts as parameter T.x and I want to get T.y also.

Comment: what do you mean by *get class out of class variable*?

Comment: No, you cannot tell from the value what class references it. Your function is passed `5`, not `T.x`, and that integer object does not tell you what references exist to it.

Comment: If you're asking "When I call `some_function(T.x)`, is there some way for `some_function` to determine the class `T`, and subsequently find `T.y`?", then, no. As far as `some_function` is concerned, the value you passed to it is a simple integer with no trackable information.

Comment: Hmm.. what about ast module?

Comment: @user1505497: what about it? You want to a) take the caller frame from `sys._getframe()` then b) obtain the source code for that caller frame, then c) parse the source so you can try and figure out what expression was used to pass in the variable? That has **many** pitfalls, because of Python's dynamic nature and flexibility. Your question is way too thin on details to even begin following that rabbit hole down.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could do something like this, using metaclasses: (Python 3):

```
class MetaT(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        for k in dct:
            #print("wrapping %s"%k)
            class Wrap(type(dct[k])):
                __parent_class__ = None
            dct[k] = Wrap(dct[k])
        return super(MetaT, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        for k in dct:
            dct[k].__parent_class__ = cls
        super(MetaT, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)

class T(metaclass=MetaT):
    x = 8
    y = 9

def get_other_attribute(arg):
    print("I got passed", arg)
    print("The parent class is", arg.__parent_class__)
    print("So I can reach attribute y:", arg.__parent_class__.y)

get_other_attribute(T.x)
```

However, this hack is **bad**, you should **not use it**, and you will have to review your design. I just made it to learn a bit about Python, and prove that it can be done with enough hacking around.